# How do I trace which method is getting executed in java when I perform some operation like clicking a button

Tags: java, swing, debugging

I am working in supporting/fixing the bugs for an existing product. The product is written completely in java and swing. Some times to debug the code I need to find out which method is getting executed when I click on a particular button or perform some operation. Is there any java utility that helps me in doing this. To attach to the debugger I need to know which method it is executing when I perform some operation. As the product is so huge
I can not predict the Classes etc based on the operation.

Answer (score 2):

Run the code in a debugger such as the one built into Netbeans IDE. You can then *step* through your code - you insert the breakpoint at the start, or in the event handler for the button click, and proceed step-by-step from there. You don't ever have to hit the "continue" button if you don't want to.

In other words, no, you don't have to understand the whole calling pattern of the code to debug it - and that's one of the advantages of a debugger, it helps you see what the program is really getting up to.

Or you may "instrument" your code by inserting log/print statements as each method is called.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a free code coverage tool like [EMMA](http://emma.sourceforge.net/) or [jaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) which have their own eclipse plugin.

Code Coverage tools help you know which parts of your code are being executed while you launch a java application or unit test so I think is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

For you to understand which method gets called when you click a button, you will need to do the following.

Consider the following sample code:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private JButton testButton;
    MyPanel() {
        testButton = new JButton("Test");
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        testButton.addActionListener(new MyButtonListener());
    }
}
```

1. Suppose you need to see the events attached with `testButton`, find its usages in the code to see what listeners are attached to it. In NetBeans and Eclipse, you can right-click on the variable and choose "Find usages" or similar action to see where all the object is being referenced.
2. Once you find the listeners, you will need to see what methods are being handled in the listener and if you mark a debug point in those methods, you can easily trace down the code execution flow.